# How do I open a textfile in access and load it in vba excel with the filepath stored in a variable?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

cracks:)

I have following code:

```
Dim TextFileConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim TextFileData As ADODB.Recordset
Dim TextFileField As ADODB.Field

Set TextFileConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set TextFileData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

TextFileConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\A7P2AZZ\Desktop\IBP DP Tool\High_Level_Data_BG.accdb"

TextFileConn.Open

With TextFileData
.ActiveConnection = TextFileConn
.Source = "FinalTable"
.LockType = adLockReadOnly
.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
.Open

End With
```

Now I want to use a variable, which I can control from excel without going into the vba-code and adjust my filepath. For this purpose I created the variable "objectname" which stores my filepath.

```
objectname = "C:\Users\A7P2AZZ\Desktop\IBP DP Tool\High_Level_Data_BG.accdb"
```

So my question is, how do I include the "objectname" into this

```
TextFileConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\A7P2AZZ\Desktop\IBP DP Tool\High_Level_Data_BG.accdb"
```

Any help is highly appreciated since I really searched in the whole world but didn't find it.

Thank you!
Best snowgun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do it like this:

```
TextFileConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & objectname
```

Comment: you are the mvp!

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking for string concatenation?
    TextFileConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & objectname